# Broadleaf Commerce Solr Issue

Tags: solr, broadleaf-commerce

I deployed broadleaf demo site on standalone tomcat server with mysql as backend and standalone solr server. I can access the solr server on 8983 port. I see that my cores are available at http://localhost:8983/solr/#/catalog and catalog_reindex (note the hash in url).

**vesion:
Solr  :solr-7.5.0,
BroadLeaf Commerce:DemoSite-develop-5.2.x**

I am getting Exception ---

**Solr Sever Log----**

2018-11-18 06:47:12.246 INFO  (qtp2131952342-18) [   x:catalog] o.a.s.c.S.Request [catalog]  webapp=/solr path=/admin/system params={wt=json&_=1542523628258} status=0 QTime=52
2018-11-18 06:49:28.752 INFO  (qtp2131952342-23) [   x:catalog_reindex] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory [catalog_reindex]  webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=javabin&version=2}{} 0 119
2018-11-18 06:49:28.754 ERROR (qtp2131952342-23) [   x:catalog_reindex] o.a.s.h.RequestHandlerBase org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field namespace
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getDynamicFieldType(IndexSchema.java:1294)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$SolrQueryAnalyzer.getWrappedAnalyzer(IndexSchema.java:436)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.DelegatingAnalyzerWrapper$DelegatingReuseStrategy.getReusableComponents(DelegatingAnalyzerWrapper.java:84)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer.tokenStream(Analyzer.java:189)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.QueryBuilder.createFieldQuery(QueryBuilder.java:240)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.newFieldQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:518)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.newFieldQuery(QueryParser.java:62)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.getFieldQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:1077)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.getFieldQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:535)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.handleQuotedTerm(SolrQueryParserBase.java:816)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:549)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:278)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:162)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:282)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:162)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:131)
    a

---

**Application Log---------**

Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/catalog_reindex: undefined field namespace
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:560) ~[solr-solrj-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:48:17]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:234) ~[solr-solrj-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:48:17]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:226) ~[solr-solrj-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:48:17]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:135) ~[solr-solrj-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:48:17]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.deleteByQuery(SolrClient.java:896) ~[solr-solrj-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:48:17]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.deleteByQuery(SolrClient.java:859) ~[solr-solrj-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:48:17]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.deleteByQuery(SolrClient.java:874) ~[solr-solrj-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:48:17]
    at org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl.deleteAllNamespaceDocuments(SolrIndexServiceImpl.java:331) ~[broadleaf-framework-5.2.7-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a field named `namespace`.

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field namespace at ..

My guess is that you're missing the configuration files from the step described in [Solrstarter](https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/catalog-and-search/deployment-models/solrstarter) referencing the configuration to use.

Also be aware that it seems that broadleaf is [designed for Solr 5.3.x](https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/catalog-and-search/deployment-models/stand-alone). If that's still the case, the schema file might need to be adopted to Solr 7.5 - as there's a few field types that have changed.